# Apply logical and

Tags: boolean, racket, logical-operators

I have an expression: `(map some-proc some-list)`
which evaluates to, say, `'(#f #f #f)`.

I want to check whether all booleans in this list are true. However, 
`(and '(#f #f #f))` returns `'(#f #f #f)`, while I heed `#f`.

Now, if I `(apply and '(#f #f #f))`, I get the error:
`and: bad syntax in: and` in the DrRacket environment. That is confusing because the Racket Reference gives the example of `(apply + '(1 2 3))` which seems to be identical to my problem.

What am I doing wrong and how I get my `#f` out of `'(#f #f #f)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use andmap for this:

```
> (andmap (lambda (x) x) '(#f #f #f))
#f
```

The problem stems from the fact that *and* is not a procedure, but a macro, in order to avoid the evaluation of all of its arguments.

It would work in Lazy Racket, though, where *and* is a procedure.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the instant answer. Then I can even directly use it in the initial expression: `(andmap some-proc some-list)`

Answer (score 2):

Just another way of doing it:

```
(foldr (lambda(x y) (and x y)) #t '(#f #f #f))
```

or I will rewrite uselpa's solution (andmap):

```
(andmap identity '(#f #f #f))
```

Comment: shoudn't that be (foldr (lambda(x y) (and x y)) *#t* '(#f #f #f)) ?